# Database strings appearing as integer values

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, types

I am loading a DataGridView using data binding from a MS-Access data table.  In this data table, some field types are sourced to other data tables so that only specific values can be selected.  These items are all strings in the database table yet they appear in the DataGridView as integer values.

Is there a way to get them to load as their string names without setting up some kind of conversion routine?

I've tried changing the column's data type and I also have the field's source set to ignore the ID column so I don't understand why I am seeing these integer values.

Comment: You can use a combobox/dropdown column to show the text but save the numeric value.  They cant (or shouldnt be) string in the table though but integer - that value translates to a text description in some other "code table"

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  Would I just bind the comboBox to that other table in the database then (the one that the field is sourced to)?

Comment: You should do a search to get the complete info, but you will remove the Int32 version of the column and replace it with a Combo column.  The datasource would be a datatable with the other data in it, and the dataproperty maps the 'translated' value (an int) to the base table

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how you are going about doing this without seeing any code. But as a last resort have you tried converting the data into a string?

```
var.tostring
```